# Passing values between C# classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session

I'm quite new in the wonderful world of C# and I'm not sure how to cope with such a problem.

I have a .NET website on Visual Studio 2008, and I have a main page, `main.aspx` (with its following `main.aspx.cs`) and a game page, `game.aspx` (also with `game.aspx.cs`).

In the main class in `main.aspx.cs` I have a static variable, `private static string _username;` and with it, a method called getUsername that simply returns this value.

Now in my game class (`game.aspx.cs`) I have an event handler, `saveButton_Click()`, and in this function I need the value of `_username`!

If it helps, a user starts on the main page, and then logs in... the variable `_username` is saved if the login is valid and then the user clicks a link to go to the `game.aspx` page!

I've looked into the internal keyword, but I am not sure how to use it in this particular example or even if it's the right thing to do in this example!

Comment: if I remember correctly, your static variable will be shared by all users of your page...each user will be saving to/from that variable...You likely want to use Session instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your main page and game page classes:

```
protected string UserName {
    get { 
        string retVal=string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UserName"]))
            retVal=Session["Username"].ToString();
        return retVal;
    }
    set{
        Session["UserName"]=value;
    }
}
```

and then access the property from your code;

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a class that inherits the `Page` class (where you would put this logic), and then make your actual pages inherit from your custom class?

Comment: Yes, but i was not sure about the asker's expertise in OOP and didn't want to confuse him with base class/derived class stuff.

Comment: Understood, mainly asking for my own sanity as I'm new(er) to .NET.

Comment: Yes, if i was doing it for myself i would have SessionHandler static class with appropriate methods exposed to set and remove session variables. Because you might want to access your UserName from somewhere else than a page, lets say a business layer. You don't want to inherit from BasePage in that case :) but you can easily access SessionHelper.UserName from anywhere as long as you reference the assembly

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, you can make a public static property in a separate class.

However, **don't**.

This model will fail horribly (or worse) when two people use your site at once.

Instead, you should use [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Sessions` to store and access the value in multiple pages:

```
//To store value in session variable
Session["UserName"] = "UserName"; 

//To access the value in the session variable
String UserName = Session["UserName"];
```

Check for Details [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you could use Forms Based Authentication which would then make it very simple to get the user name, via `User.Identity.Name`.